# About making 4 by 4 or bigger square matrices

Tags: macros

I am writing some notes with a lot of similar big matrices involved. So I wish to use `\newcommand` to make typing easily. For a 3 by 3 matrix, I can use the following code:

```
\newcommand{\mtrthr}[9]{\begin{pmatrix} #1 &#2 &#3 \\#4 &#5 &#6\\ #7 &#8 &#9 \end{pmatrix}}
```

But when the matrix grows bigger, how can I define this similar to the above? Since LaTeX only allows 9 arguments in the command. Thank you.

Comment: What editor are you using? TeXstudio has a good Wizard to insert matrices. See here http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION18

Comment: I am using CTex. It is just a Latex allowing Chinese characters.

Comment: I see. I just know I can insert a matrix from menu........ Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As you say, you can only have 9 arguments here. So you have to think about some other approach which uses not more than 9 parameters per used command. You could, for example, define a command for each row of the matrix.

To be honest, I do not see the advantage here, I would recommend to have dummy matrices in your preamble which you can copy where ever you like.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\mtrthr}[9]{\begin{pmatrix} #1 &#2 &#3 \\#4 &#5 &#6\\ #7 &#8 &#9 \end{pmatrix}}
\newcommand*{\rowfor}[4]{#1 &#2 &#3 &#4}
\newcommand{\mtrfor}[4]{\begin{pmatrix} #1 \\#2 \\ #3 \\ #4 \end{pmatrix}}
%% Dummy for 2x2
%xxx & xxx \\ xxx & xxx 
%% Dummy for 3x3
%xxx & xxx & xxx \\ xxx & xxx & xxx \\ xxx & xxx & xxx
%% Dummy for 4x4
%xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\ xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\ xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\ xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx
%% Dummy for 5x5
%xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\ xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\ xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\ xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\ xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx


\begin{document}    
\[\mtrthr{arg1}{arg2}{arg3}{arg4}{arg5}{arg6}{arg7}{arg8}{arg9}\]

% With editors like TeXstudio, you get the following code from the automatic code competition. You can then jump through the arguments with Ctrl-right and add the numbers you want
\[\mtrfor{\rowfor{arg1}{arg2}{arg3}{arg4}}{\rowfor{arg2}{arg2}{arg3}{arg4}}{\rowfor{arg3}{arg2}{arg3}{arg4}}{\rowfor{arg4}{arg2}{arg3}{arg4}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know I can insert matrix from menu. So I write my own code. For 2 by 2 matrix, I think the above code is faster, for 3 by 3, it's about the same. For bigger matrix, It's better to insert a matrix from menu. Thanks.